# Waiting different time between function calls when using setInterval in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, settimeout, setinterval

On my site two words are being printed letter by letter over and over again. I want 0.1s between the letters being printed, and when I get a full word, I want to wait for 3s before I print the new one. I used `setTimeout` but it's not working. What is the problem with my code?

```
var app = angular.module("app", []);

app.controller('mainCtrl', function ($scope) {
    var values = ['.com', 'available'];
    var index = 0;
    $scope.comval = '';
    function changeText (){
        if(values[index].length == $scope.comval.length) {
            $scope.comval = '';
            index++;
            if (index >= values.length) {
                index = 0;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            $scope.comval = values[index].substring(0, $scope.comval.length+1);
            $scope.$apply();
            console.log($scope.comval);
        }
    }

    setInterval(changeText,100);
});
```

The effect can be seen on [this](http://vegas.jaysalvat.com/) site. Look at the part depicted in the image below:

[image]

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/to61vaL6/4/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To fix this, I used `setTimeout` (calls the function *once* after the specified time) instead of `setInterval` (calls the function over and over again). Since we want it to be called not just once, we put the call to `setTimeout` inside the function (`changeText`) so it adds a timer to call itself. This lets us use different delays for different situations - 100 ms for when we are just printing a new letter, and 3000 ms when we have finished printing a new word.

```
var app = angular.module("app", []);

app.controller('mainCtrl', function ($scope) {
    var values = ['.com', 'available'];
    var index = 0;
    $scope.comval = '';
    function changeText (){
        if(values[index].length == $scope.comval.length) {
            $scope.comval = '';
            index++;
            if (index >= values.length) {
                index = 0;
            }
            //We have printed a full word!
            //Wait 3000 ms to call the function again.
            setTimeout(changeText,3000);
        }
        else
        {
            $scope.comval = values[index].substring(0, $scope.comval.length+1);
            $scope.$apply();
            console.log($scope.comval);
            //We have printed only a letter.
            //Just wait 100 ms before calling the function again.
            setTimeout(changeText,100);
        }
    }

    //Start it all off.
    setTimeout(changeText,100);
});
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/to61vaL6/7/).

Comment: Thanks a million Anders , you're great

Answer (score 0):

Use `$interval` like this:

```
$interval(changeText, 100);
```

Also, don't forget to inject `$interval` into your controller.

**EDIT:**

Since you want to run the function after three seconds use `$timeout` service:

```
$timeout(function() {
    $interval(changeText, 100)
}, 3000)
```

Again, inject `$timeout` in the controller.

Comment: $interval is the same with setInterval(changeText,100); ?

Comment: $interval is angular's own service.

Comment: if i do this, this function run slowly , but i'd like to call this each 3s with this speed

Comment: what do you mean by 'slowly'? It will run after every 3 seconds. I am not getting you...

Comment: sry if i'm not good to explain ,I don't want to run it every 3seconds , i want to call it every 3 seconds

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/93677/discussion-between-sani-and-tarun-dugar).

Comment: Now if i use $timeout function run once , how can i repeat this every 3 seconds ?

Comment: use $interval instead of $timeout. Just replace $timeout by $interval.

Comment: nope, it's not what i want ,   $interval(function() {
    $timeout(changeText, 300)
}, 1000)

Comment: vegas.jaysalvat.com please see this link , and my edited question , for where you can see

Comment: that's what i mean for delay

Comment: let's chat if you'd like :)

Comment: @TarunDugar The question has been edited since you posted this answer. When you answered it was quite vague, but now it is clearer. Your answer does not fit the current question, so I would like to suggest that you consider either deleting your answer or updating it to fit the question. Thank you.